# Random result between queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

The following queries have the same result, although they have different seed numbers:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers ORDER BY RAND();
SELECT * FROM Customers ORDER BY RAND(5);
SELECT * FROM Customers ORDER BY RAND(1290);
SELECT * FROM Customers ORDER BY RAND(0.121);
```

How do I write a query that returns the **same** result for **a specific seed** but **a different result** for **a different seed**?
I want to keep the random order for the same seed.

Comment: Reopened as the duplicate doesn't address making the order repeatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something unique and deterministic per row. I assume you have a `CustomerId` column below.

You can then use something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers
ORDER BY HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(CustomerId, @Seed) AS binary(8)))
```

Or potentially generate a row numbering using your unique and deterministic value and combine this with your `@Seed` to produce an integer to use to seed `RAND` per row.

NB: Originally I tried

```
ORDER BY RAND(CHECKSUM(CustomerId) + @Seed)
```

But changing the `@Seed` changed the value but did not change the relative ordering of rows. It looks as though small adjustments to the seed just produce small adjustments in the random value correlated with the ordering of the seed (e.g. try `SELECT RAND(6), RAND(7), RAND(8)`)

Wrapping with `HASHBYTES` will hopefully mitigate this and mean small adjustments in the value still lead to larger differences in the eventual value used for ordering.